# Add an additional Administrator to APIM instance

Tags: azure-api-management

I have my APIM instance that is connected to AAD. How can I add a second administrator to the instance? Users signing in through the Developer Portal show up with the Developer role. But how do I add a second administrator?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add second administrator to the APIM service as mentioned in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-administrators-group-)

> Administrators groups is an immutable system group. Azure subscription
> administrators are members of this group. You cannot add a user to
> this group.